# Confusion regarding Dynamic arrays

Tags: arrays, vbscript

Ok so I am using the code below to read and display text files into a HTA with VBScript, it loops through all the text files present in a folder (Notes). I have it parsing returns and have removed the file extension from display.

What I would like to do is build 2 arrays, one for the file names, one for the text file content so I can use them in other parts of the script to output as needed.

I understand I need a dynamic array as such within the loop it needs to expand it's intsize, it's just the implementation I am unsure of, particulary as it could probably be a 2 dimensional array to keep the filename and it's content together. Here is the code.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "Notes\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
   For Each objFile in colFiles
   If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "TXT" Then

        Files = objStartFolder & objFile.name
        Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Files, 1)

        strExt = Left(objFile.name, Len(objFile.name)-4)
        strNote = Replace(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCRLF, "<br>")

    objReadFile.Close

        document.write strExt & "<br><br>"
        document.write strNote & "<br><br>"

    else
    document.write ="File was empty"

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Or use a dictionary.

Comment: @eurotrash Prefer arrays for performance versus COM objects.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this using a 2 dimensional array fairly easily.

Because you know the number of files before there is no need to use `Preserve` to dynamically keep resizing the array as you loop through the files, instead just declare a dynamic array and then use `ReDim` to set the initial dimensions.

```vb
Dim data()

...

Dim index
ReDim data(1, colFiles.Count - 1)

For Each objFile in colFiles
  ...
  data(0, index) = objFile.Name
  data(1, index) = strNote
  index = index + 1
Next
Erase data
```

*<sup>`...` denotes existing code omitted to emphasizes the additions</sup>*

#### Update:

OP would like a full example because it's not clear how the above code fit's into their example, so here goes;

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, objFolder, colFiles, objFile, objReadFile
Dim objStartFolder, Files, strExt, strNote

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "Notes\"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Dim data(), index

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
'No need for preserve as we have the Count from the colFiles File Collection.
ReDim data(1, colFiles.Count - 1)

For Each objFile in colFiles
  If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "TXT" Then
    Files = objStartFolder & objFile.name
    Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Files, 1)

    strExt = Left(objFile.name, Len(objFile.name)-4)
    strNote = Replace(objReadFile.ReadAll, vbCRLF, "<br>")

    objReadFile.Close
    'Release resources
    Set objReadFile = Nothing

    document.write strExt & "<br><br>"
    document.write strNote & "<br><br>"
    
    'Populate the array
    data(0, index) = objFile.Name
    data(1, index) = strNote
    index = index + 1    
  Else
    document.write ="File was empty"
  End If
Next
'Release resources
Erase data
Set colFiles = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

*<sup>This code is untested</sup>*

I tested this myself with an example that you can call using cscript

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim fs, folder, files, file
Dim i, r, c

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set folder = fs.GetFolder("C:\")
Set files = folder.Files

Dim data()

ReDim data(1, files.Count -1)

For Each file In files
  data(0, i) = file.Name
  data(1, i) = file.Path
  i = i + 1
Next

For r = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
  For c = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
    WScript.Echo "data(" & c & ", " & r & ") = " & data(c, r)
  Next
Next
Erase data
Set files = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```

Run this from the command line using `cscript.exe` as `wscript.exe` will produce a ton of popup boxes.

Comment: Sorry Lankymart, I am ok with logic statements, settings variables and basic code, but arrays confuse me a little. I shall need a little more explaination than that so I can comprehend. Could you please edit your post and include your code with mine, and explain methods of outputting the data (say with innerhtml, even just a variable). PS: The size of the array would only be limited by the amount of txt files in the Notes directory.

Comment: @Ctrlaltdenied The code should just fit around your existing code but will modify the answer later. Out at the moment and commenting via my mobile.

Comment: Fair enough fella, I think I have an idea where it would go, but I don't quite *get* arrays yet, and how they can be manipulated. I'd rather understand what it is I'm putting in. Thanks, and no issues.

Comment: @Ctrlaltdenied When it comes to 2 dimensional arrays easiest way to think about them is like columns and rows in a table. The 1st dimension is the columns and the 2nd dimension is the rows, so in this example you have 2 columns and however many rows dictated by `colFiles.Count - 1`.