# Classic ASP extract data from a SQL Database and put it into array

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

A simple table (Table1) with two fields (numer of monthly Apples and number of monthy Oranges for two seasons) in SQL Server 2000. I need to extract the values of those fields using Classic ASP and populate two arrays. Constraints: those arrays were defined already by an out-of-the-shelve app that I need not to touch too much because I am a beginner in Classic ASP and I might do something wrong.

Definition of those arrays are as follows:

```
Dim m_arrApples, m_arrOranges
```

I have succeded to connect to database, extract data and then display it in a browser (format figures). Yet, when I need to transfer it in an array (in order to be taken over by that out-of-the-shelve app and process it (displaying in a graph format) I encounter an error. Here it is my code:

```
'Open connection with SQL Server
Dim conn
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=" & NameServer & ";database=" & DataBaseName & ";uid=" & NameUser & ";pwd=" & DataBasePassword & ";" 

'Open table and all records for further processing 
dim strSQL
strSQL = "select * from " & Table1
Set rst = conn.Execute(strSQL)

'Going through the records in the table and try to get values of each field and allocate them to the array
If rst.BOF And rst.EOF Then
    Response.Write "No data"
Else

i=0

Do While (Not rst.EOF)
i=i+1

'The line below confirms that the data extracted from database is displayed in the browser
'in its primary form (not graph), but that means I did it correctly up to this point 
Response.Write rst("Apples") & "/" & rst("Oranges") & "<br>"

m_arrApples(i)= rst("Apples")         ' THE ERROR IS AT THIS LINE. HERE THE SCRIPT IS STOPPED
m_arrOranges(i)= rst("Oranges")

rst.MoveNext
Loop
End If
```

The error is:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' 
Type mismatch
```

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: When working with dynamic arrays you need to use [`ReDim Preserve`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c850dt17(v=vs.84).aspx) to define the new size, if you already know the size use a fixed array *(if you know you'll have 10 values use `Dim m_arrApples(9)`)*.

Comment: Yes. it worked. Thanks! Where do I credit your answer? Not used stackoverflow for long time ...

Comment: It's not so much that you're using the wrong method to resize the arrays, it's more that you *haven't defined any arrays*, dynamic, fixed, or otherwise. Lankymart's answer relies on the fact that `Redim` will actually convert a non-array variable into an array, but your code would be more understandable if you dimmed your arrays as, well, arrays: `Dim m_arrApples(), m_arrOranges()`.

Comment: @Martha same old argument, the difference is minor and as long as you `ReDim` inconsequential. However there is still one compelling reason to use `Dim yourvar()` and that is `IsArray()` will always be `True` where as `Dim yourvar` is just a variable so it will return `False` - see [Dim output() versus Dim output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26059851/692942)

Comment: @Gab2020 that was a comment, I've [added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41637851/692942) now.

Answer (score 2):

When working with dynamic arrays you need to use

```
ReDim Preserve m_arrApples(i + 1)
```

to increase the size of the Array, if you already know the size use a Fixed Array *(if you know you'll have 10 values use `Dim m_arrApples(9)`)*.

---

#### Useful Links

- [A: Confusion regarding Dynamic arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33123241/692942)
- [A: Declaring a dynamic array not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26059851/692942)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Getrows() method of the Recordset

```
'Create a Recordset
Dim objRS
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open "SELECT * FROM Table1", objConn

'now read the Recordset into a 2nd array
Dim aTable1Values
aTable1Values = objRS.GetRows()
```

You can then loop through the 2 dimensional array thus :

```
Dim iRowLoop, iColLoop
For iRowLoop = 0 to UBound(aTable1Values, 2)
  For iColLoop = 0 to UBound(aTable1Values, 1)
    Response.Write(aTable1Values(iColLoop, iRowLoop) & "<br>")
  Next 'iColLoop

  Response.Write("<p>")
Next 'iRowLoop
```

more information here
https://web.archive.org/web/20210619191820/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=161

Comment: That doesn't get you two single dimension arrays, it get's you one multiple dimension array, you still have to break it down into two arrays - *"I need to extract the values of those fields using Classic ASP and **populate two arrays**. Constraints: those arrays were defined already"*. Also OP has [already commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636801/classic-asp-extract-data-from-a-sql-database-and-put-it-into-array#comment70474905_41636801) before you posted. `GetRows()` is great I use it all the time but no benefit in this scenario.

Comment: It does however give you a size for the array to help with the redim.

Comment: @BrianT: um, you do know about `objRS.RecordCount`, don't you?

Comment: @Martha - granted, you could use that but you'd have one too many wouldn't you? ;-)